# How to get the image size of an image file in monotouch without loading it?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, nsdictionary, cgimagesource

How to get the image size of an image file in monotouch without loading it in memory?

I tried to use CGImageSource from the MonoTouch.ImageIO namespace, as indicated in the Apple documentation and in this blog post:

[oleb.net](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/accessing-image-properties-without-loading-the-image-into-memory/)

But this code doesn't work:

```
public Size GetImageSizeFromImageFile (string image_file_path)
    {

        CGImageSource imageSource = CGImageSource.FromUrl (NSUrl.FromFilename (image_file_path));

        if (imageSource == null) {
            // Error loading image
            Console.WriteLine ("Error loading image info for file: " + image_file_path);
            return Size.Empty;
        }

        NSDictionary imageProperties = new NSDictionary ();
        imageSource.CopyProperties (imageProperties, 0);

        int width = (int)imageProperties.ValueForKey (new NSString ("kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth"));
        int height = (int)imageProperties.ValueForKey (new NSString ("kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight"));


        Console.WriteLine (@"Image " + image_file_path + " dimensions: " + width + " x " + height+" px");

        imageProperties.Dispose ();

        return new Size(width, height);
    }
```

Casting to strings doesn't make any difference, the field returns empty.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The latest MonoTouch releases makes it a lot easier to get the image properties using the new `GetProperties` method. E.g.

```
using (var src = CGImageSource.FromUrl (NSUrl.FromFilename (filename))) {
    CGImageOptions options = new CGImageOptions () { ShouldCache = false };
    // do not forget the '0' image index or you won't get what you're looking for!
    using (var p = src.GetProperties (options, 0)) {
        Console.WriteLine ("{0}x{1}", p.PixelWidth, p.PixelHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I create the options in monotouch? I can't find any documentation on this, and the code is not easy to translate from obj-c.

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait for the next release then.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in Mono Touch. I tested the code in XCode with the same image in Mono Touch and it worked in XCode.

In Mono Touch after calling the `imageSource.CopyProperties(imageProperties,0)` `imageProperties.Keys` Count is 0

So you should create a bug report at bugzilla.xamarin.com/